# Validar Imagen en typeScript o JavaScript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript

Estoy haciendo un formulario para recogida de datos de usuarios en una aplicación web, en el cual se le puede añadir un avatar a través de un `input file`. Este lo tengo limitado para que acepte solo archivos con extensiones correspondientes a imágenes pero mi duda reside en que yo puedo crear un archivo con un `script` y darle una extensión `.jpg` por ejemplo y claro con esto mi aplicación traga.

La imagen la puedo analizar

```
const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = (event: any) => {
      console.log(event);
      this.avatarUrl = event.target.result;
      console.log(this.avatarUrl);
    };
    reader.readAsDataURL(this.avatarSelected);
```

pero a la hora de analizarlo no encuentro nada por dónde atacar para diferenciar imágenes reales de `scripts` ocultos.

Graciñas de antemano por las respuestas.

Comment: Echa un ojo a esta respuesta:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/29672957/538323

Comment: Aquí está la solución en inglés: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53145396/filter-images-in-typescript-or-javascript/53145788#53145788